# Reading the first line of a txt and converting it to int, but returning another value [C]

Tags: c, arrays, string

I've been trying to read a txt which has a specific structure:
 The first line indicates the n-1 lines the whole txt file has.
 All the other lines have the "structure" of a card (it's number and it's pattern).

ex: I have a txt which stores 13 cards, so the file in itself has 14 lines:

```
13
A T
2 P
3 D
13 P
2 P
4 C
8 D
11 T
8 C
9 C
10 T
9 T
7 P
```

(Note: T stands for clubs, D for diamonds, C for hearts and P for spades, it's in spanish).
 I've tried extracting the first line to then create a dynamic array with the number given so that I can store each line in that array, but I fail to get the first value.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int leerLinea(){
    char contenido[1];
    FILE* pArchivo;
    pArchivo = fopen("Mazo.txt","r");
    if (pArchivo == NULL){
        printf("No hay nada aqui!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    else{
        fgets(contenido,3,pArchivo);
        printf("%s\n", contenido);
    }

    fclose(pArchivo);
    return contenido[0];
}

int main(){
    int a;
    a = leerLinea();
    printf("a's value is: %d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it I get:

```
13
a's value is: 49
```

Why is it returning other value, when it should be returning 13?

Comment: `char contenido[1]` -> `char contenido[3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `fgets(contenido,3,pArchivo)`, you read in a string into a buffer that is to small for capturing at least 2 digits and the string termination character; For that statement, it should be at least `char contenido[3]`.

The main issue is, however, that you mix strings with "pure" integral values, i.e. you read in a string but expect it to be converted correctly to a number simply by accessing the first digit of that string; Note that if `contenido` containded `"13"`, `contenido[0]` would give character value `'1'`, which in ASCII is `49`.

To overcome this, read in the value as a number, i.e. using `"%d"`-format:

```
int leerLinea(){
    int contenido = 0;
    FILE* pArchivo;
    pArchivo = fopen("Mazo.txt","r");
    if (pArchivo == NULL){
        printf("No hay nada aqui!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    else{
        fscanf(pArchivo,"%d",&contenido);
        printf("%d\n", contenido);
    }

    fclose(pArchivo);
    return contenido;
}
```

Comment: Typically a _line_ of input needs 2 `char` for the 2 digits, 1 to read/consume the line-feed and then 1 for the null character. So rather than "should be `char contenido[3]`", I'd suggest `contenido[4 /* or more */]`

Comment: @chux: right in general; but in this specific case, OP used `fgets(...,3,...)`, and only because of that I suggested `char contenido[3]`... adapted the answer, hope it makes it a bit more clear...

Comment: Many ways to solve an issue.  It will be interesting to see what OP does when trying to read the next data as `fscanf(pArchivo,"%d",&contenido);` leaves the trailing  `'\n'` in the stream.  UV for a an improve answer.

Comment: @chux: right; as OP closes the file after having read the number we can just guess...

Answer (score 1):

1 - Read a *line* of text with sufficient space for each character in the line, the *line-feed* and a *null character*.  The below is 4 characters, so a buffer of 6 is needed.

```
13 P
```

Further, there is little gained by being so stingy with line buffers.  Suggest 2x the maximize anticipated size to allow for some growth, leading/trailing whitespace.

```
#define LINE_MAX (4 + 1 + 1)
char contenido[LINE_MAX * 2];
```

2 - When reading a line, do not hard code in the 3, use `sizeof()` for consistent, easier to maintain code.

```
   // fgets(contenido,3,pArchivo);
   fgets(contenido, sizeof contenido, pArchivo);
```

3 - Rather than return the first character of a string  (the code for the character `'1'` is 49), convert the string into an `int/long` with `strtol()` or `atol()`, etc. [@Nicolas Guerin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46595030/2410359)

```
// return contenido[0];
return atoi(contenido);
// or
return strtol(contenido, NULL, 10); // better
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return atoi(contenido[0]);
```

The probleme you've got is that you return a char in an int function, every char as an integer value. That's true but not the decimal value of the char, the ascii value.

Atoi convert a char into an int.

ps: the way you do, it will only return `1` in the exemple